# Some point features don't appear in QGIS after sync from QField, but are visible on other smartphones

Tags: qgis, qfield

I really don't understand why it's not working how I expect it to. On the website I can see that the changes were applied, and also on other smartphones it's fine, but when I want to sync it with the computer, some points are missing. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to gove more detail of your project, its set-up etc. Look at community guidelines, and review other posts regarding QFieldSync ti give you an idea of what detail a question should contain.